# When is it better to use trunc() instead of int() to convert floating type numbers to integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, truncate

`trunc` and `int` functions return the same output for every float type inputs that I have tried.

They differ in the way that `int` can also be used to convert numerical strings to integers.

So I have a two-fold question:

1. I would like to know if, apart from strings, is there any input for which `trunc` and `int` give different outputs?
2. If not, when is it better to just use `trunc` to convert floating type numbers to integers?

Comment: If the output type and value for floats is the same for both, what classifies **better** for you?

Comment: @Bazingaa I think the question is more along the lines of whether anyone can think of a use case where it would actually be correct to use `trunc` over `int`, not which one is *better*. Confirming that they are actually identical could be an answer as well.

Comment: The exception of already mentioned example of `strings` already rules out the possibility of them being identical.

Comment: So one possible use case is if i want the cast to throw an error if some other dtype than `float` is used, i could use `trunc`.

Comment: @Bazingaa perhaps due to some fundamental difference in their implementation one of them is implemented faster in case of very big numbers.

Comment: @whateven: So speed is what you were looking for. That explains

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) and [`math.trunc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.trunc) have a somewhat similar relationship as [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) and [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr). `int` delegates to a type's [`__int__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__) method, and falls back to the [`__trunc__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__trunc__) method if `__int__` is not found. `math.trunc` delegates to the type's `__trunc__` method directly and has no fallback. Unlike [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), which are always defined for `object`, both `int` and `math.trunc` can raise errors out of the box.

For all the built-in types that I am aware of, both `__int__` and `__trunc__` are defined sensibly where appropriate. However, you can define your own set of test classes to see what errors you get:

```
class A:
    def __int__(self):
        return 1

class B:
    def __trunc__(self):
        return 1

class C(): pass
```

`math.trunc(A())` and `math.trunc(C())` will both raise `TypeError: type X doesn't define __trunc__ method`. `int(C())` will raise `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'C'`. However, `int(A())`, `int(B())` and `math.trunc(B())` will all succeed.

In the end the decision as to which method to use is one of connotation. `trunc` is inherently a math operation similar to `floor`, while `int` is a general purpose conversion, and succeeds in more cases. In other words, `int` can attempt to convert something like a string to an integer, while `trunc` works on `floats`, which already have a clearly defined integer portion.

And don't forget about [`operator.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.index) and the [`__index__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__) method.

Comment: Note also that `__int__` should (must?) return a value of type `int`, while `__trunc__` merely needs to return a value of type `Integral` (an abstract base class). Commonly, but not necessarily, the concrete type of the returned value is `int`.

Comment: @chepner. Should :) If you use an improperly implemented `__int__` very carefully, it won't cause you any problems.  I've definitely tried similar things.

Answer (score 1):

`math.trunc()` works about 10% faster than `int()`; at least on my computer configuration.

Comment: That's not surprising since `int` does type conversions while `trunc` does not. How did you benchmark that?

Comment: For me I found that `int` is >2x slower than `trunc` for floats on python 3.12. With several different floats I get the same (consisten) results. e.g. I set `x = 1/137` and then `%timeit int(x)` gives `34.5ns`, while `%timeit trunc(x)` gives `16.7ns`.

Comment: But the strange thing is with integers `trunc` becomes a lot slower. With e.g. `x=42` I get `31.4ns` for `int(x)`, but `39.3ns` for `trunc(x)`.

Comment: Oh and btw, `math.trunc` also does type conversion in the case of `float`.