The difference between math.trunc() and int() in python
what is the difference between math.trunc() in math module and the int function in python both of them return remove the fractional part of a number and I think it has some reasons that python let them stay .
for example
math.trunc(4.76)=4
int(4.76)=4
In what situations are each used?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52223610/when-is-it-better-to-use-trunc-instead-of-int-to-convert-floating-type-numbe

Note that math.trunc doesn't necessarily return in int, just something that implements the number.Integer interface. If you really want an int (e.g., range(int(my_value))), then use int(). But if you want to truncate but work with custom objects that you might not even know about, then math.trunc.

int itself will use its argument __trunc__ method (just like math.trunc) if its argument doesn't define __int__ or __index__. Theoretically, each method could return a different value depending on why you need an integer. I'd argue that you should prefer math.trunc.

(float, in particular, seems to implement __int__ and __trunc__ identically, and does not define __index__ at all, so math.trunc and int should be equivalent for float arguments.)
